# ionic shows empty ion-content

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

i am using ionic 5 (angular) with latest updates.
my builds are working fine for android and iphone.

when i start the app with ipad simulator or real device, the app shows the header(logo and title) of the app and also admob-plugin in the footer ( banner )

the only thing i am missing is my content of the app .. everything in my `<ion-content>` area is missing..

when i try to use the livereload function `ionic cordova emulate ios -l` the app also shows correct the ion-content also on ipad.
i think this would be the only situation how i could debug anything to find whats going on?

are there any possibilitys to debug or get a console output of the builded ipad version where the ion-content area is missing?

Comment: Have you tried using Safari? See this https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios#debugging-ios-apps

Comment: hi and thanks for your answer. yes of course i tried this already, but as i told, if i start the app with livereload everything works fine.. also on the ipad.. if i try to debug it with the normal build where the error happens, the developer console is empty